# Xampp and Mavericks

Tags: macos, xampp, osx-mavericks

I recently updated to **Mavericks** and I am using **XAMPP 1.7.3** and I get a `child pid 2094 exit signal Bus error (10)` in my error_log everytime I try to go to my website.

Any idea what would cause this error?

Everything was working fine before I upgraded to **Mavericks**.

Answer (score 0):

backup your httpd-vhosts.conf if needed

go to apachefriends.org get the latest osx package ( 1.8.3 with php 5.5)
open the dmg and run the install wizard, **!! check both core files and developer files !!**

replace the new httpd-vhosts.conf

uncomment vhosts conf in httpd.conf

DONE

Comment: Is it necessary to backup also htdocs folder with all projects and mysql databases? @diosney: Has it helped to u? 

I have similar problems but some kind of projects work, others not esp. those which uses Zend Framework.

Comment: And what if it's necessary to stay with PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 0):

re - Backing up folders and db - probably not but it never hurts to have a second copy.

I always backup php.ini & http.conf as well so I can compare new settings with older ones if I see a performance change

BTW - some of your config settings will be different after the install.  For example, low level errors (like E_NOTICE) may be reported by default.  This may require edits to your php.ini file.  For example, the default setting for error_reporting is set to error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT which is fine for development but messy for production (you may see a whole bunch of variable declaration errors) to turn the low-level errors off - set

```
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT &~E_NOTICE
```

or comment out the error_reporting setting (defaults to reporting everything except for the E_NOTICE errors).